# Running ionic project from mac to windows

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4, ionic5

I want to run one of the ionic project from mac to windows but I have error while doing npm install it does not generate node_modules too. Can someone help me or have any idea with this? I already tried upgrading all the versions to the latest and also downgrade node from 16 to 14 and ionic6 to ionic 4 but its still the same. Here is the error, I also tried downloading node-gyp [Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdpHH.png)

Comment: npm outdated comand ?

Comment: I already tried the latest npm version but the error is still the same

Answer (score 0):

The 4th last line of the logs has your answer. Node hasn't been properly installed on the machine or the incorrect command is being used.

Verify the installation & commands.